# how can i fix vercel path error when deploying

Tags: deployment, path, next.js, vercel

My project works on local , but i try to deploy to vercel, i got this error `Module not found: Can't resolve '../artifacts/contracts/Cartoonz.json' in '/vercel/path0/utils'`;

Here is my utils/interact.js

[my path already exist on const contract, right ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAp3J.png)

Comment: How you're deploying your application to Vercel? Have you tried vercel command with force flag? Like this `vercel --force`. Doing this will clear the build cache.

Comment: i am using vercel website , should i use to vercel CLI ? for write this command (vercel  --force)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, anything text-based should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause for this issue is the fact that some filesystems are case-insensitive, however **Vercel deployments use a case-sensitive filesystem**. Because of this,  change **the letter-casing in filenames** on your local machine to match exactly the path

Answer (score -1):

You have to run `vercel` from a directory that **contains** the `assets` folder, because the parent directories won't be uploaded to vercel.

Can you please post a screenshot of your folder structure, and tell us where you run the `vercel` command?